# How to solve $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> How can I evaluate the following integral $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$$

This is taken from a definite integral where $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

**My attempt:**

Multiplied by conjugate
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\\=\int \frac{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx}{(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}$$
$$=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx}{1+x-1+x}$$
$$=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})dx}{2x}$$

1. If I use $x=\sin^2\theta$
   $$\int \frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}+\cos\theta\right)}{2\sin^2\theta}\sin2\theta\ d\theta\\
   =\int \left(\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}+\cos\theta\right)\cot\theta d\theta$$
2. If I use $x=\tan^2\theta$
   $$\int \frac{\left(\sec\theta-\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta}\right)}{2\tan^2\theta}2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta d\theta\ d\theta\\
   =\int \frac{\left(\sec\theta-\sqrt{1-\tan^2\theta}\right)}{\sin\theta\cos\theta} d\theta$$

Should I use substitution $x=\sin^2\theta$ or $x=\tan^2\theta$?. I can't decide which substitution will work further. Please help me solve this integration.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot "solve" an integral. Integral is not a problem.

Comment: @Alexey sorry for my title i corrected it. you might want to answer now

Comment: Just to be clear- you’re trying to evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 [\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}]$. That’s undefined because the integrand is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: @Alexey What is a problem?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw, something that can be solved :). Like a mathematical exercise. Equations can also be solved. Sums, products, integrals cannot be solved, they can be calculated/computed/evaluated.

Comment: @Alexey In what sense do you say that an integral is not a problem/mathematical exercise?  When you "evaluate" an integral, you are solving an equation.  For example, when you "evaluate" $\int f(x) dx$, you are solving for g(x) in the equation $\frac{d}{dx} \left[g(x)\right] = f(x)$.  You are trying to find a function whose derivative is f(x).  That is a puzzle and therefore a problem/mathematical exercise, not a simple evaluation.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw, there is an integral, and there is a problem to compute that integral. You are right that evaluating an integral amounts to solving an equation. Just like evaluating $3 - 2$ amounts to solving the equation $x + 2 = 3$.

Answer (score 11):

You can split the integral into two parts
$$\int \frac{(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}{2x} \, dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}\,dx+\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x}\,dx\right].$$
Solve these separately as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}\,dx & =\int \frac{t^2}{(t^2-1)}\,dt && (\text{ let } 1+x=t^2) \\
& =\int \frac{t^2-1+1}{(t^2-1)}\,dt\\ 
& =\int 1 \, dt+\int \frac{1}{(t^2-1)}\,dt\\ 
& =t+\frac{1}{2}\left[\int \frac{1}{(t-1)}\,dt-\int \frac{1}{(t+1)}\,dt\right]\\
&=t+\ln\frac{|t-1|}{|t+1|}+c\\
&=\sqrt{1+x}+\ln\frac{|\sqrt{1+x}-1|}{|\sqrt{1+x}+1|}+c\\
\end{align*}
Observe that the second part is pretty much the same. If you use $x=-u$, then
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x}\, dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{u}\, du.$$
So you can write the answer without any further computation.
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x}\, dx=\sqrt{1\color{red}{-x}}+\ln\frac{|\sqrt{1\color{red}{-x}}-1|}{|\sqrt{1\color{red}{-x}}+1|}+c$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})^2}}$$
$$=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$
Let $x=\sin\theta\implies dx=\cos\theta d\theta$
$$=\int \frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}}$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}}\quad \quad \left(\because \cos\theta=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
$$=\int \frac{\left(1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)d\theta}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
$$=\int \left(\frac12\csc\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\ d\theta$$
$$=\ln \left|\tan\frac{\theta}{4}\right|+2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+C$$

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{sin^2(\theta/2)} \ne |sin(\theta/2) |$?

Comment: OP did mention the condition for $x$ so assuming $x$ varies  from $0$ to $1$ and hence $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}, \sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ are positive hence $$\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}=\left|2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\quad \quad \left(0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Indeed, $x$ is in between $-1$ and $1$ but how is it known that $x\ge 0$?

Comment: for $\sqrt{1\pm x}$ to be defined we can conclude $-1<x<1$

Comment: Ahhh, I got it. Either $0\le \theta \le \pi$ or $\pi\le \theta \le 2\pi$. In either case, $\theta/2$ is $\le \pi$ but $\ge 0$. Hence $\ sin$ is positive.

Comment: we also have to exclude $x=0$ for $-1<x<1$ but for $0<x<1$ it's works fine

Comment: Exactly! But x=1,-1 are both legal. $0$ is not.

Comment: @Koro sorry i forgot to mention the limit of $x$ if from $0$ to $1$ in my question because i took it from a definite integral for $x=0$ to $x=1$

Comment: @Jyerkimenon: Even if $x$ varies from $- 1$ to 0, still this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{aligned} I &:= \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{2 x} d x =\frac{1}{2}\left[ \underbrace{\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x}d x}_{J}+\underbrace{\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x} d x}_{K}\right] \end{aligned}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x} d x \\
&=\int \frac{1+x}{x \sqrt{1+x}} d x \\
&=\int \frac{1+x}{x} d (\sqrt{1+x}) \\
&=\int\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right) d(\sqrt{1+x}) \\
&=\int \frac{d (\sqrt{1+x})}{(\sqrt{1+x})^{2}-1}+\sqrt{1+x} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}\right|+\sqrt{1+x}+c_{1}
\end{aligned}
$$$$
K \stackrel{x\mapsto -x}{=} \sqrt{1-x}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{\sqrt{1-x}+1}\right|+c_{2}
$$
Now we can conclude that $$
I=\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left| \frac{(\sqrt{1+x}-1)(\sqrt{1-x}-1)}{(\sqrt{1+x}+1)(\sqrt{1-x}+1)}\right|+C
$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t= \sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x} $ to have
\begin{align}
&(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})dx=(2-t^2 )dt\\
&(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})^2=4-t^2 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\ dx
=\int \frac{2-t^2}{4-t^2} dt= t-\tanh^{-1}\frac t2+C\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variable $x=\sin 2t$, we have

$$\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{\cos^2t+2\cos t\sin t+\sin^2t}-\sqrt{\cos^2t-2\cos t\sin t+\sin^2t}=2\sin t.$$

Then

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}=\int\frac{2\cos2t}{2\sin t}dt=\int\left(\frac1{\sin t}-2\sin t\right)dt
\\=\text{arcoth}(\cos t)+2\cos t+C.$$

---

From the biquadratic equation

$$4\cos^2t\,(1-\cos^2t)=x^2$$ you draw $\cos t$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$

By Rationalizing,

$I=\frac{1}{2}[\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x}} {{x}}dx + \int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}} {{x}}dx ]$

This Can easily be integrated by seperating,

For $\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x}} {{x}}dx $,

Let,

$1+x = t^2$

$dx=2tdt$

$\therefore I_1=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x}} {{x}}dx = \int\frac{2t^2}{t^2-1}dt$

After little arranging,

$I_1 = 2[\int dt + \int \frac{dt}{t^2-1}]$

$I_1 = 2[t+\ln \frac{|t-1|}{|t+1|}]+C$

$\frac{I_1}{2}= \sqrt{1+x}+\ln \frac {|\sqrt{1+x}-1|}{|\sqrt{1+x}+1|} + C$

Similarly,
$\frac{I_2}{2} = \sqrt{1-x}+\ln \frac {|\sqrt{1-x}-1|}{|\sqrt{1-x}+1|} + C$

$\therefore I = \frac{1}{2}[I_1+I_2]=\sqrt{1+x}+\ln \frac {|\sqrt{1+x}-1|}{|\sqrt{1+x}+1|} + \sqrt{1-x}+\ln \frac {|\sqrt{1-x}-1|}{|\sqrt{1-x}+1|}+C$

$I = \sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x} + \ln \frac{|(\sqrt{1+x}-1)(\sqrt{1-x}-1)|}{|(\sqrt{1+x}+1)(\sqrt{1-x}+1)|} + C$

*Hope this answers your questio*n